# Eclipse freezes when trying to install

Tags: eclipse, installation

so I have a problem. I accidentally deleted Eclipse folder and I wanted to install Eclipse again. But when I run installation it freezes the moment I run it, and I have to exit it...please help me

Answer (score 0):

It would be informative to observe and mention any system error during installation attempt. By the way, I hope you are installing the right version for your operating system and more so, you have the recommended system requirement like RAM size, processor speed. I suggest:

1. Restart your system.
2. Use a system tool like Advanced System Care (free) and scan your system.

Comment: I'm installing right version for my OS and I have 100% requirement RAM size,processor speed...I scanned system with Advanced System Care and I restarted. It's still not working.

Comment: Any error notification that can provide a clue during installation?

Comment: There's nothing. It just freezes and when I click on it is says to exit or keep waiting.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't know what happened but I tried to install it 2 times, it freezed and didn't work. When I tried third time it worked. :D So yeah. Magic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Everytime I tried to install Eclipse, the installer froze at some point. Turned out it was a problem with the firewall. I tried the installation over a hotspot from my phone and it worked.
Might not be the problem for you, but I thought I leave this here, as I was trying for quite a while and almost gave up.